# How to query a Datatable using LINQ and add values to a List?

Tags: c#, linq, .net-4.0, linq-to-objects

Sample Class:

```
public class ProductData
{
    private Guid ProductID { get; set; }
    private string ProductDescription { get; set; }

    public ProductData(Guid pID, string pDescription)
    {
        this.ProductID = pID;
        this.ProductDescription = pDescription;
    }
}
```

Create a list of ProductData:

```
    private static List<ProductData> GetProductDataList()
    {
        // code to populate DataSet ds here

        DataTable dtReport = ds.Tables[0];
        List<AssetData> lstProductData = new List<ProductData>();
        int index = 1;
        foreach (DataRow row in dtReport.Rows)
        {
            lstProductData.Add(new ProductData(new Guid(row["ProductID"].ToString()), row["Product"].ToString()));
            index++;
        }

        return lstProductData.ToList();
    }
```

Code works perfectly fine and as expected. But, I think the **foreach loop** can be avoided using LINQ. I try to utilize LINQ as much as possible for various reasons (cleaner looking code is one of the reason - correct me if I am wrong).

Is there any way I can achieve the same thing as above using LINQ and with minimum code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be done using `Select` and `ToList`:

```
var lstProductData = dtReport.Rows.Cast<DataRow>()
    .Select(row => new ProductData(new Guid(row["ProductID"].ToString())
        , row["Product"].ToString()))
    .ToList();
```

Comment: Thanks @ Servy. Is it important to have cast to DataRow?

Comment: @Learner It won't compile without it, so I'd think so, yes.  You could also use `dtReport.AsEnumerable()` instead, if you prefer.

Comment: How is dtReport.AsEnumerable() different from casting. Could you please explain both a little bit?

Comment: @Learner It's not, which is why I said you could use either.